# JS Ошибка при сокрытии элемента

Tags: javascript, веб-программирование, html5, button, localstorage

Всем привет подскажите почему не работает функция. Цель функции считать с local storage время в которое кнопка была нажата. И если с момента нажатия не прошло определенное время, то не показывать её.

```js
var date = new Date();
var trueTime = date.getTime();

function check() {
  if ((localStorage.getItem("timeToUnblock")) & trueTime < localStorage.getItem('timeToUnblock')) {
  document.getElementById("RegisterButton").style.visibility ="hidden";
alert("wait");
  } else if (!(localStorage.getItem("timeToUnblock"))){

 } else{
    alert("block time is end!"); 
 }
}
```

```html
<script>check();</script>
<div id="RegisterButton">
<input type="button" value="Кнопка" onclick="timeCounter()" >//onclick- сохраняет время
</div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Разобрался. Выдаёт ошибку потому что `<script>check();</script>` вызываем раньше инициализации кнопки, поэтому он её и не находит. Поставил после кнопки, все заработало.